# WPF reference width of grid column

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a more elegant way than the one I found to reference the width of a grid column for the construction of a embedded grid? Can't I access the actual width of a certain grid's column in a better way? Could I also have a two-way connection, so that if a column in the child-grid gets too wide, the column in the parent grows to fit the content?

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>  
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="26" />
        <RowDefinition Height="26" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="col0" Content="This"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="col1" Content="is"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="col2" Content="a"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" x:Name="col3" Content="test."/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=col0}" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=col1}" />     
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="The" />
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="same width" />                  
      </Grid>

  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Grid` control supports a number of "Same Size" properties that let you specify that columns or rows in the `Grid` should all be the same size, without you having to worry about what those sizes are.

To use it, add the `IsSharedSizeScope` attached property to the `Grid` control:

```
<Grid Name="Root" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    . . .
</Grid>
```

Then, on the columns that you want to be the same size, you specify a name for the `SharedSizeGroup` property:

```
<Grid Name="Root" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid Name="InnerGrid1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column1" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column2" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        . . .
    </Grid>

    <Grid Name="InnerGrid2>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column1" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column2" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        . . .
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In this example, there are two different columns in two different `Grids` that will always be the same size.